# Download File from frontend magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, download

I have a problem with download function from frontend. 
I make a simple Download function in my block.

**`Practice/Attachment/Block/Frontend/Attachment.php`**:

```
protected function DownloadFile() {

    $file = 'media/attachment/Doc1.pdf';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }

}
```

This is my template **`design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/attachement.phtml`**:

```
<div class="attachment">
    <?php
    foreach ($this->getCollection() as $status)
    {
        $image_of_download_button = 'Doc1.pdf';
        $value = $this->getCollection()->getItemById($status->entity_id)->getData('title');
        $link  = $this->getCollection()->getItemById($status->entity_id)->getData('uploaded_file');
        $link2 = 'media/attachment/Doc1.pdf';
        $elo = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'attachment/'.$image_of_download_button;
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $linkModel?> ">
            <img src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'attachment/'.$image_of_download_button?>" width=1200px height="100px" align="center" style="margin-left: 20px">
            <p> AAAAAAAA </p>
        </a>
        <br>
        <button name="button_download" onclick=" <?php  $this->DownloadFile(); ?> ">Click me</button>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

But if i reload the page the file is autodownloaded and if i click the button nothing is happening. 
I wanna download the file when i press click on button, this is the reason for use oneclick. 
Why i do wrong?

I just wanna make a function for frontend to download a file (pdf for exmaple) for a product.

Comment: Should it be `onclick=" <?php  $this->DownloadFile(); ?> "` instead of `onclick=" <?php  $this->sendFile(); ?> "` ?

Comment: no, sorry, i make a mistake on my code post here. i correct the code.

Comment: my function was sendFile, but i change here in DownloadFile to make it clear

Comment: Write this function in your module controller and on button button click just hit that controller action your file will start downloading on click.

Comment: i try to write the function in the controller, but i dont know how to acces the controller in my block. To use my function in my block, i use layout.

Comment: <block type="practice_attachment/frontend_attachment" name="practice" template="catalog/product/view/attachment.phtml">

Comment: So, how i can use the controller? I realy apreciate if i understand this. I know to use controller in grid admin, but i dont know to use the controller for blocks in frontend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make some modification:

Step 1 : Replace your button code:

From:

```
<button name="button_download" onclick=" <?php  $this->DownloadFile(); ?> ">Click me</button>
```

To :

```
<button name="button_download" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Step 2:
add following code at the end of file :

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    /* practice = your module name,index = controller, index function */
    window.location = "<?php echo $this->getUrl('practice/index/index/');?>";
}
</script>
```

Step 3: Create a controller `IndexController.php` for example:

```
<?php 
class Practice_Attachment_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action{
public function index() {

    $file = 'media/attachment/Doc1.pdf';

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }

}
?>
```

Clear cache and check this.

Comment: i want to download wishlist item list from frontend as a pdf formate. is it work for this?